# How to reload a page in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7

when user wins the game if he want to play the game again in this case page needs to reload again.
for this I have tried the below code but exception has came.what is the correct way to reload a page.

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/NumericEasy.xaml"+
                                "?Refresh=true&random={0}", Guid.NewGuid())));
```

Comment: This looks fine to me. What exception was thrown? What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you're getting this exception:

> Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or
>   begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'

You should set the UriKind parameter. Change your code a bit:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/NumericEasy.xaml?random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.Relative));
```